# ¿Cómo declarar un string como llave primaria en un migration de laravel 5.2 y luego llamarla como llave foranea?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

Intente ocupar el siguiente código:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('microbuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('patente');
            $table->string('marca');
            $table->string('modelo');
            $table->integer('agno');
            $table->integer('linea_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('linea_id')
                ->references('id')->on('lineas');

            $table->timestamps();
        });

    }
```

Luego al intentar llamar el 'run' como llave foranea me da error:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('microbus_paradero', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('microbus_patente')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('paradero_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('microbus_patente')
                ->references('id')->on('microbuses');
            $table->foreign('paradero_id')
                ->references('id')->on('paraderos');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Al parecer el método "unsigned" sólo funciona con variables de tipo integer y como mi variable es string, puede que el error radique ahí. Pero es la única forma que conozco y nose como declarar una llave foranea que haga referencia a un campo string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la tabla `microbuses` puedes especificar la llave primaria de la siguiente manera, en una línea, en el método `up()`:

```
$table->primary('patente'); // o el campo que desees
```

En efecto el método unsigned es únicamente para enteros. Más información (para MySQL): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html

La declaración de la llave foránea que haces es correcta, siempre y cuando el campo exista en la otra tabla:

```
$table->foreign('microbus_patente')->references('patente')->on('microbuses');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal el error que veo es que el la tabla microbuses no hay campo id
y en esta parte estas haciendo referencia a el

```
$table->foreign('microbus_patente')
            ->references('id')->on('microbuses');
```

por otra parte si lo que deseas es poner como primarykey un string puedes interntar con esto recuerda que los indices tienen que ser unicos para evitar problemas

```
 $table->string('patente')->unique();
 $table->foreign('microbus_patente')
                ->references('patente')->on('microbuses');
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned` significa "Sin signo" solo funciona para números enteros.

La pregunta es... **¿Por qué un string como llave primaria?**

El performance de MySQL se vería seriamente afectado con este tipo de campo, si lo que quieres es proteger tus IDs puedes usar otra columna y usarla para mostrarla posteriormente en tus vistas o respuestas, algo así como un **UUID** o un código único.

Es mejor dejar el típico entero como llave primaria para respetar el autoincrement, el unsigned y tener más facilidad a la hora de hacer las relaciones.

También puedes crear un **hashid** a través de [Laravel Hashids](https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids) que lo que hace es codificar de manera segura tus IDs para no exponerlos.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui un ejemplo de como crear una **primary key personalizada**:
Primero modifica tu modelo en la ruta **app/Models** agregando estas lineas:

class User extends Authenticatable
{

```
/**
 * The "type" of the auto-incrementing ID.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $keyType='string';
    /**
 * The primary key associated with the table.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey='nombre_de_la_primaryKey';
```

Luego en tu archivo de la ruta **/database/migrations** agrega tu primary key asi:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('nombre_de_la_primaryKey', 30)->primary();
```

Espero esto resulelva futuras dudas.
Saludos.